# How can I improve the Git Portuguese version by correcting translations?

Tags: git, translation

I've noticed that in Git, several sentences, like "Changes not staged for commit" or "use 'git restore ...' to discard changes in working directory" are not translated into Portuguese. I would like to contribute to the Git project by correcting these translations and improving the overall Portuguese version.

I've already found the pt_br.po file in the [Git Po Repository.](https://github.com/git-l10n/git-po/blob/master/git-gui/po/pt_br.po) However, upon reviewing this file, I couldn't find translations for the specific examples I've mentioned in my question.

To proceed with the corrections, I would appreciate guidance on the following:

1. Are there any additional repositories or files specifically dedicated to translating Git messages and prompts?
2. Should I directly propose my translations and corrections for review, or is there a specific workflow or collaboration platform for language localization in Git?

Any advice or tips would be awesome! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside `po` directory at Git's repository root, you'll find two files named `README.md` and `TEAMS`:
https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/po

The first one describes the translation process in Git project, the second one tells you which are the members and team leader for each language, as well as a dedicated Git repository from which branches are eventually merged into main trunk.